# SQL 'merging' columns from result sets into one result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been pulling my hair about how to write a particular view within the constraints of MySQL.

The following tables and columns are of importance:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

-- Joins payments to invoices. The sum of all `invoice_currency_value`s is the balance paid towards an invoice.
CREATE TABLE `financial_transactions_invoices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  `invoice` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `invoice_currency_value` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

-- Lists items (services) available to purchase.
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  `value` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

-- Each instance represents that the `item` has been purchased.
CREATE TABLE `item_instances` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  `invoice` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `invoice_currency_rate` decimal(11,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

-- Any number of tax instances can exist for an item instance and indicate this tax has been applied to the associated item instance.
CREATE TABLE `tax_instances` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  `item_instance` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Now, I need a view that lists for each row,

- **the invoice number**
- **the total value of the invoice**
- **the total tax on the invoice**
- **and the total value of payments made towards the invoice**

However, I can't figure out how to get these three separate queries into the same result set of one row per invoice, e.g.

```
inv_no  total_value     total_tax       payments
1       150             5               120
2       120             10              20
3       10              0               10
4       1000            150             1150
```

I have written the following query which produces the desired result, but due to the 'no subquery' rule in MySQL views, it is not acceptable.

```
SELECT `invoice_id`, SUM(`total_value`) AS `total_value`, SUM(`total_tax`) AS `total_tax`,
    SUM(`paid_balance`) AS `paid_balance`
FROM
(SELECT `invoices`.`id` AS `invoice_id`, SUM(`items`.`value` * `item_instances`.`invoice_currency_rate`) AS `total_value`,
    NULL AS `total_tax`, NULL AS `paid_balance`
FROM `items`
    JOIN `item_instances` ON `items`.`id` = `item_instances`.`item`
    JOIN `invoices` ON `item_instances`.`invoice` = `invoices`.`id`
GROUP BY `invoices`.`id`
UNION
SELECT `invoices`.`id`, NULL, SUM(`tax_instances`.`value`), NULL
FROM `tax_instances`
    JOIN `item_instances` ON `tax_instances`.`item_instance` = `item_instances`.`id`
    JOIN `invoices` ON `item_instances`.`invoice` = `invoices`.`id`
GROUP BY `invoices`.`id`
UNION
SELECT `invoices`.`id`, NULL, NULL, SUM(`financial_transactions_invoices`.`invoice_currency_value`)
FROM `financial_transactions_invoices`
    JOIN `invoices` ON `financial_transactions_invoices`.`invoice` = `invoices`.`id`
GROUP BY `invoices`.`id`) AS `components`
GROUP by `invoice_id`;
```

Without tackling the problem in the way I have, I can't think of any other way I can do it **within MySQL**.

Any ideas? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two views. One with the `UNION` Subquery, and one with the outer query.